# Reasons for using OSMBonusPack versus OSRM (Open Source Routing Machine)?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmdroid, osrm, osmbonuspack

UPDATE to question:

If we are running our own database and tile server, do we also need to run our own instance of OSRM to get routing via OSMDroid using `OSRMRoadManager`?  OR if not running our own, pull from another OSRM instance somewhere?

---

We are setting up an instance of Open Street Map data and a tile server on our own server, that will provide data for a mobile app.

My question is about routing: is there reason to set up Open Street Routing Machine / OSRM (http://project-osrm.org) vs using something like OSMDroid (https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) or OSMBonusPack (https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack)?  OSRM seems to have some pretty heavy server requirements, but will it have other benefits, perhaps by keeping things easier on the front end?

We are creating our own OSM server with the hope/expectation that we will start generating large amounts of traffic, and we are trying to understand the best strategy for the routing.  Most of the traffic will be through either our mobile app or mobile browsers.  For the routing, we don't really need much more than a polyline connecting start and end points via some reference points that will we determine to force the route through certain streets.  Thanks for any help strategizing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I figured it out.  Hopefully my confusion will help others find out this answer more quickly.

For connecting a different tile service just for visualization, there is already a class `XYTileSource.java` in OSMDroid.  But for getting to your own routing data (your own instance of OSRM) via the OSMBonusPack, you work with the class `OSRMRoadManager`, perhaps changing the string that points to the OSRM demo site, but also just using `setService()` with the url to your own OSRM server.